# Collision detection with octrees realized with python-fcl

Tags: python, collision-detection, ubuntu-20.04, point-cloud-library, octree

I want to finish the collision detection with point cloud represented by Octrees. With the `python-fcl` lib, I tried the following code snippet by myself

```
x = np.random.random([5, 3])
y = np.random.random([5, 3])

object1 = fcl.OcTree(0.1).insertPointCloud(points=x)
object2 = fcl.OcTree(0.1).insertPointCloud(points=y)

t1 = fcl.Transform()
o1 = fcl.CollisionObject(object1, t1)

t2 = fcl.Transform()
o2 = fcl.CollisionObject(object2, t2)

request = fcl.DistanceRequest()
result = fcl.DistanceResult()

ret = fcl.distance(object1, object2, request, result)
```

However, I got the error like this

```
File "src/fcl/fcl.pyx", line 140, in fcl.fcl.CollisionObject.__cinit__ValueError
```

So far, there are no other examples of octree with `python-fcl`, even in [official document](https://github.com/BerkeleyAutomation/python-fcl).

Has anyone converted the point cloud to an Octree and completed collision detection?

Help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

nah bro its something to do with your machine. try using replit.com for running your code or use jupyter notebooks. appreciate your code

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but I think you didn't understand what I meant

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).